# Why is the loopback device needed on a client side of Stunnel?

Tags: stunnel, loopback

[This SANS Institute guide](http://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/vpns/stunnel-ssling-internet-services-easily-754) states that

> "On the client side, a port listening on the loopback interface of the
>   local system would send/receive data on the clear-text protocol and
>   tunnel out on an ephemeral port to connect to the secured port of the
>   remote system"

Interestingly, this is not stated about the server side, so my first question is: **Is this statement true for the server side as well?**

Then, this [Installing stunnel on your windows machine](https://www.cs.umd.edu/faq/samba/stunnel_windows.html) guide implements the aforementioned statement nicely (I actually followed it an verified it is working).

I understand that the following directive in the stunnel.conf file redirects the original (clear-text) traffic from port 139 to the encrypted port 1445:

```
client = yes
[smb]
accept=10.1.1.2:139
connect=samba.cs.umd.edu:1445
```

But I don't understand *how* it does it.

More specifically:

1. Why is a loopback adapter needed to facilitate this?
2. Why was the IP address `10.1.1.2` chosen for the 'accept' port?
3. Is default gateway needed? (if so, why/how does it work on a system that does not have any default gateway specified for the loopback adapter?)